# Injecting Vault Secrets while docker build in Azure Devops CI/CD pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, hashicorp-vault, cicd

I have database migration running at the time of docker build currently using .env file for passing the variable. So I need to integrate vault secrets while docker is building the image and fetch secrets from vault itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vault Agent Templates - https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/agent/template